# cocotb simulation with Aldec

Tags: cocotb, active-hdl

I am doing some EDA tools test with cocotb as a testbench. I am running simulations with icarus and verilator without problem, however, with Aldec I have got a problem at "runsim.tcl".

The output of the console is

```
 Welcome to VSIMSA!
 This message was printed from `startup.do' macro file.

 runsim.tcl(5) error: parse error
 @if [string length<--
 make[1]: *** [/c/users/mehdi/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/cocotb/share/makefiles/simulators/Makefile.aldec:176: results.xml] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Mehdi/testcocotbVerilator'
 make: *** [c:\users\mehdi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cocotb\share\makefiles/Makefile.sim:82: sim] Error 2
```

I would appreciate if someone could advise me how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag says active-hdl - then you should probably use the new `SIM=activehdl` from cocotb master.
`SIM=aldec` is for Riviera-PRO.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am actually not able to find makefile.activehdl in the makefile folders. I can see e.g. ".aldec", ". icarus", etc but not ".activehdl". am I using an old version of cocotb?

Comment: Your version may not strictly be "old" , but still not new enough :) Please see https://docs.cocotb.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cocotb-installation-via-pip and follow the instructions to install the development version of cocotb.